# Problem with aligning textView to the end of LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I am making chatting app and want to style messages as they are in messenger app.

And this is my code to style them:

```
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  params.setMargins(400,0,10,10);
                      params.gravity = Gravity.END;
                        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

                        linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

This is my XML code:

```
         <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And my TextViews are added to this ^ linear layout.

And this is what I am receiving in app: (don't translate messages they are only for test purposes and they are stupid) [image: screenshot]

And I do not why those gaps are made, someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal behavior of textView. You can test on the SIGNAL app by typing a long word and it will move it to the next line and on the upper line, you will get to see the same space left as you are getting in yours.

**If you mean to change the alignment of text** in the textview then you can define the `textAlignment`  property of textView according to your requirement.

Comment: but how can I delete this space, there must be way I can do it, because it looks ugly

Comment: Try the attribute `android:breakStrategy`  for textView. Basically, it will break the long words into two-line, currently, it is moving the whole text to the next line leaving an undesired space in the above line.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because of the long length of the last word of your messages, if Android sees that he can't put a sequence of chars (word) into the current line, then it types it down on the next one, so to solve this problem you have 2 different solutions (or more):

1- But it may live a gap from the other side

```
 textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
```

2- It centers the text in its container which may live a gap from both sides

```
 textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

**Good luck.**